# Rails4: image_path different in view and in test despite being called with the same param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have the following view partial in my Ruby on Rails 4 project:

```
<div class="badges">
  <% @user.badges.each do |badge| %>
    <img
      height="47"
      width="40"
      src='<%= image_path("badges/#{badge}.svg") %>'
      onerror='this.src=\'<%= image_path("badges/#{badge}.png") %>\'; this.onerror=null;'
    />
  <% end %>
</div>
```

It's tested in a view test as follows:

```
it "shows the badges" do
  User::ALLOWED_BADGES.each do |badge|
    badge_image = image_path("badges/#{badge}.svg")
    expect(rendered).to match "src='#{badge_image}'"
  end
end
```

The rendered view shows the following:

```
<img
  height="47"
  width="40"
  src='/assets/badges/cga50-92b4667cd8419a060a981a9ac5ff0152a3cd011141cae5f9964240d55aa5d88b.svg'
  onerror='this.src=\'/assets/badges/cga50-3d0a4668a8b44c8518760546dc6f253d4287ba2ddd11e6ad577d7916f05d055f.png\'; this.onerror=null;'
/>
```

But the string value being matched against is `src='/images/badges/cga50.svg'`, not `src='/assets/badges/cga50-92b4667cd8419a060a981a9ac5ff0152a3cd011141cae5f9964240d55aa5d88b.svg'`.

Why does `image_path` create the correct url in the redered view, but not in the test?

Comment: Could it be: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7218

Comment: @JimEdelstein yep — that looks exactly like it.  I'll post my workaround below.

Answer (score 1):

As Jim Edelstein pointed out in the comment above, [this is a bug in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23621).

After some digging I found it's also [a slightly contentious issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23621#issuecomment-183092265) amongst the rails devs and the PR to 'fix' it is done but will be part of Rails 5, not Rails 4.

My work-around is to change the test as follows:

```
shared_examples 'shows the badges' do
  it "shows the badges" do
    User::ALLOWED_BADGES.each do |badge|
      expect(rendered).to match /src='\/[a-z]+\/badges\/#{badge}-[a-f0-9]+\.svg/
    end
  end
end
```

It's a bit grubby but it works.